# PHP standard function list

Tags: php

I am looking for a list of all standard PHP functions with their arguments ($needle, $haystack etc.) in a single file. I don't want any more details apart from these.

I have tried googling this, but the keywords are very general purpose.

I need it mostly for reference.

Comment: I want it in a single file - nothing else apart from what I specified

Comment: http://php.net/quickref.php (no arguments)

Comment: That's close, but I also need the arguments

Comment: Well youd have to click through but: http://www.php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php - if not that you could down load the docs and build from there. Using that list for all function and methods names it should be relatively easy to scan the help files and pull out what you need then output to your desired format.

Comment: Oh, sabof's is even better. Or you know you could skip all this and just use an IDE that has code hinting and manual integration ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a list of all standard library PHP functions in a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692604/need-a-list-of-all-standard-library-php-functions-in-a-single-file)

Comment: @prodigitalson it might be is easy, but documentations are meant to be read by people. Building a robust script that would filter out what I need might be more difficult than it seems at first

Comment: It wouldnt need to be that robust since all youre looking for is name and signature. its just DOM crawling with DOMDocument or one of the many HTML selector libraries and all that info is really accessible via css or xpath selectors.

Comment: I also wanted to add it to scripts. Someone somewhere writing a dot instead of a comma would cause problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a list, but it wouldn't be hard to generate, using `get_defined_functions` and Reflection.

```
<?php

$funcs = get_defined_functions();

foreach ($funcs['internal'] as $func) {
    $f = new ReflectionFunction($func);
    $line = '';

    $line .= $func . ' ( ';

    $params = '';
    $optional = 0;
    foreach ($f->getParameters() as $param) {
        if ($param->isOptional()) {
            $params .= '[ ';
            $optional++;
        }

        $params .= ($param->isPassedByReference() ? '&' : '')
                   . '$' . $param->getName()
                   . ', ';
    }

    $line .= substr($params, 0, -2) . str_repeat(' ]', $optional) . " )\n";
    echo $line;
}
```

Which gives output like this:

```
mysqli_query ( $link, $query )
mysqli_real_connect ( $link, [ $host, [ $user, [ $password, [ $database, [ $port, [ $socket, [ $flags ] ] ] ] ] ] ] )
```

Not ideal, but it might do the job for you, and it will take account of whatever extensions you have loaded.

Comment: I need to try it to see how well it works, but it looks like more than what I have been asking for.

Comment: @sabof The principle shouldn't be hard to extend to what you need, though.

Answer (score 1):

Added Bytes' [PHP cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet/) is pretty good. It's by no means a comprehensive list...but for reference, it's a great place to start!

Answer (score 1):

PHP API:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file, you can try out this: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) or binaries: [PHP Manual](http://windows.php.net/download/). There you can download a big file for offline use.